# What's wrong with this Perl replacement?

Tags: perl

Using the code below, I want to remove the `.log` at the end. I seem to be doing everything right according to *[perlrequick](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrequick.html)*. Where did I mess up?

> **test.pl**

```
my $file = "ooout.log";
print $file."\n";
my $file =~ s/\.log//g;
print $file."\n";
```

> **output**

```
$ perl test.pl
ooout.log

$
```

Comment: Wow, five replies all saying the same thing in under a minute, is that a record?  It looks like elusive won.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're redeclaring `my $file` -- remove the `my` prefix to fix this. This would be caught if you started your script with

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

You would have seen:

```
"my" variable $file masks earlier declaration in same scope at
```

Comment: So `use warnings;` does the same thing as running with `perl -w`?  I did not know that.

Comment: @jnylen: yes, but `use warnings;` is better for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 8):

Others have pointed out your problem with `my`.

I'd like to note that your substitution code does not exactly match your spec.
It will delete all occurrences of the string `.log` from your file name.

If you only want to delete `.log` at the end of your string, don't use the `g` modifier, and do use the end-of-string anchor `$`:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $file = "ooout.logical.log";
print "$file\n";
$file =~ s/\.log$//;
print "$file\n";
```

Output:

```
ooout.logical.log
ooout.logical
```

Answer (score 3):

Try removing `my` from the replace-line:

```
$file =~ s/\.log//g;
```

It seems like you are reinitializing `$file`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the second `my`, then it will work.

`my` (somewhat simplified) declares a *new* variable. You are declaring `$file` twice, so the second `my` makes perl forget the value in the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying "my $file" in the third line, so you're defining another variable.

Try:

```
my $file = "ooout.log";
print $file."\n";
$file =~ s/\.log//g;
print $file."\n";
```

Answer (score -1):

The second `my`.